# How to Parse a Glossary Section of a Website with BeautifulSoup & strip HTML tags

Tags: html, parsing, tags, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to Parse this page 
http://www.lib.uts.edu.au/about-uts-library/corporate-information/library-glossary 
and get just the

Title,
Description

for each section and that's it, no tags.
I parse the page and try to search for all `<title>` and `<p>` tags but it doesn't produce the right results.

I am using Python 2.7 and BeautifulSoup 3-2-0

Here is a sample of my code:

```
import urllib2, sys
address = sys.argv[1]
html = urlib2.urlopen(http://www.lib.uts.edu.au/about-uts-library/corporate-information/library-glossary).read()
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
def printText(tags):
        for tag in tags:
                if tag._class_==NavigableString:
                        print tag,
                else:
                        printText(tag)
        print ""
printText(soup.findALL("p"))
print "".join(soup.findALL("p", text=re.compile(".")))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for, but I suspect you are looking to get the term and definition out from this page. Looking for the <title> and <p> tags is not really what you need. You should look for attributes that make a tag unique. In this case, looking at the <span> tag shows that there is a class attribute that uniquely labels the terms. This can be used to isolate the sections that you need. I suggest looking more closely at the documentation for find/findAll. Below is some code that will get you most of the way there.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

url = 'http://www.lib.uts.edu.au/about-uts-library/corporate-information/library-glossary'
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen(url))

paragraphs = [x.parent for x in soup.findAll(name='span',attrs={'class':'definition'}) if x.parent.name == 'p']
for p in paragraphs:
    name = p.find(name='span',attrs={'class':'definition'}).text
    text = p.text.replace(name,'')
    print '-'*80
    print name
    print text
```